# Merge multiple rows in SQL table into one row in new table

Tags: postgresql, sql

I have a table with a similar structure to this example:

| id | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | 10 |
| 1 | name2 | 15 |
| 1 | name3 | 25 |
| 2 | name1 | 30 |
| 2 | name2 | 57 |
| 2 | name3 | 40 |

And I need the table output structured like this:

| id | name1 | name2 | name3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 15 | 25 |
| 2 | 30 | 57 | 40 |

Is it possible to do this? Additionally, the existing table has about 100000 unique id values, so I cannot insert the table values manually as I have seen on other similar questions asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the crosstab function from the tablefunc extension.

First install the extension:

```
create extension tablefunc;
```

Then you can use the crosstab function like this:

```
select * from 
  crosstab('select id, name, value from your_table order by 1,2',
    $$values ('name1'), ('name2'), ('name3')$$)
  as ct(id int, name1 int, name2 int, name3 int);
```

Here's an example output:

[image]

Comment: also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query